# How to make rest service recognize specific user?

Tags: android, spring, rest, authentication

I am developing a spring backend rest service (using hibernate). I've got an android app client from which the user can create their account (register and log in).
How can I make a rest service which recognize what user is sending the request (after log in). To hibernate, could I use a proper 'User' Entity and get data to see which user is the owner?
Is it ok to return user_id after log in and then send this id with every request? Or should I use something like session ID or maybe send username and password with every request to authenticate particular user?

Comment: If you are using Spring-security in your server-side, then you can simply put the JSESSIONID as a cookie parameter and send the request. The value for JSESSIONID is retrieved when you will perform authentication over /j_spring_security_check.

Comment: Do you use Spring Security at the moment?

Comment: At the moment I don't use any security mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

I use JWT to communicate between mobile apps and my api server ( usually Node.js server )

Check this [introduction](http://jwt.io/introduction/) to [jwt](http://jwt.io/)

What is love is once user is authenticated just exchange the encrypted token which can carry a lot more than just the user_id of authenticated user.

Some additional links which explains JWT.
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/51294/json-web-tokens-jwt-as-user-identification-and-authentication-tokens

https://auth0.com/blog/2014/12/02/using-json-web-tokens-as-api-keys/